# Read csv file and update the mysql table with php code

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import-from-csv

I have a csv file downloaded from ftp server with curl and now i need to update the datas in mysql table based on the guid field in csv. Can anyone please help me on this?

Datas of csv file:

GUIDcsvinterest_amyloidosiscsvinterest_ahuscsvinterest_complement_mediated_diseasescsvinterest_hemophiliacsvinterest_hyperoxaluriacsvinterest_PNHcsvinterest_porphyriascsvdouble_opt_in_datecsvopt_outcsvdate_addedcsvdate_modified
X1000csvFalsecsvFalsecsvFalsecsvFalsecsvFalsecsvFalsecsvFalsecsv2018-02-01 13:21:00csv2018-02-21 09:00:00csv2017-02-01 13:00:00csv2018-02-21 09:00:00

First 3 lines are field names of the table and last 2 lines are the values that needs to be updated.

Tried this so far:

```
$csvFile = 'csv/filecurl.csv';
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($csvFile));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {

$csv[] = $row;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Any effort so far?

Comment: Read about [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)... it may shed some light.

Comment: That is _not_ a CSV.  You know what those letters stand for, right?

Comment: Its either a bogus paste, or ... actually like that. Either way, I couldn't find a way to format it to be clearer to read.

Comment: @Debu, you approved the edit on this question that added a line-break that was not in the original file that you posted.  Please clarify whether or not your actual file/data has that line-break or not.  It may seem trivial, but it makes a big difference.

Comment: `$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "ttt";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$sql = "";
$query = <<<eof
    LOAD DATA INFILE '$csvFile'
     INTO TABLE tableName
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'csv' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (guid,interest_amyloidosis,interest_ahus)
eof;

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Tried this code to save from csv file too but no luck